# Invalid Object Name - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I am creating a stored procedure in SQL Server via SSMS.

I have written the stored procedure below, however when I click **execute** it am given the error:

*Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure NewQuestion, Line 11
Invalid object name 'hgomez.NewQuestion'.*

the table is ownership is correct. (hgomez.Questions)

```
USE [devworks_oscar]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [hgomez].[NewQuestion]    Script Date: 10/23/2011 23:55:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [hgomez].[NewQuestion]
    (
    @QUESTIONNAME nvarchar(50),
    @QUESTION_ID int OUTPUT
    )

AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    INSERT INTO [Questions] (QuestionText) VALUES (@QUESTIONNAME)
    SET @QUESTION_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your stored procedure exist?  This error indicates that it can't find the object, in this case your SP.  Did you previously create it with a create procedure?

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419710/invalid-object-name-sql-server-2008-r2-stored-procedure/23430576#23430576

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was a fan of always prepending my `CREATE` statements with an explicit check for existence and dropping if it was found.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'NewQuestion' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'hgomez')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE hgomez.NewQuestion
END
GO

-- this is always a CREATE
CREATE PROCEDURE [hgomez].[NewQuestion]
    (
    @QUESTIONNAME nvarchar(50),
    @QUESTION_ID int OUTPUT
    )

AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    INSERT INTO [Questions] (QuestionText) VALUES (@QUESTIONNAME)
    SET @QUESTION_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN
```

That can be a bit of hassle with regard to permissions so others use an approach wherein they create a stub method only to immediately `ALTER` it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'NewQuestion' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'hgomez')
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE hgomez.NewQuestion AS SELECT ''stub version, to be replaced''')
END
GO

-- This is always ALTER
ALTER PROCEDURE [hgomez].[NewQuestion]
    (
    @QUESTIONNAME nvarchar(50),
    @QUESTION_ID int OUTPUT
    )

AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    INSERT INTO [Questions] (QuestionText) VALUES (@QUESTIONNAME)
    SET @QUESTION_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN
```

Comment: Nice idea about a stub, never thought about it. I might probably choose to put PRINT instead of SELECT, though, but that may be just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 5):

This script tries to modify a procedure that already exists; it doesn't create the procedure.

To create the procedure use [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [hgomez].[NewQuestion]
```

Once the procedure exists, you can modify its definition by using [`ALTER PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [hgomez].[NewQuestion]
```

Comment: Quick solution. I must have overlooked the alter statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26775310/2211788 explained

> If you drop and re-create a stored procedure it gets a new objectid - the list of stored procedures in SSMS is linked to the id it knows at the time the list was built. If you re-create it but don't refresh the stored procedures folder then any attempts to edit it will indicate the procedure is not found as the id has changed.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once when I had two instances of SSMS open and I was working on the one I opened first.  Closed them both down, reopened and it worked fine.