# Invalid object name sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting this error while trying to modify the existing stored procedure. 
`"Invalid object name [dbo].[BackupDB]"`

I was able to create this stored procedure but when I click on modify option to modify this stored procedure system shows me the above error. You see the attached image.

Also i am getting same error when try to execute this command. It won't find BackupDB

```
EXEC BackupDB @backupLocation='C:\SQLBackups\', 
                              @databaseName=’wmas_subs’, @backupType='F'
```

http://i61.tinypic.com/6oj32s.png

Comment: Are you sure the stored procedure exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Object Name - Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870501/invalid-object-name-stored-procedure)

Comment: i restart SQL Server and its now working. Possibly the intense issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to refresh the folder of Stored Procedure on your Management Studio

Answer (score 2):

If you drop and re-create a stored procedure it gets a new objectid - the list of stored procedures in SSMS is linked to the id it knows at the time the list was built. If you re-create it but don't refresh the stored procedures folder then any attempts to edit it will indicate the procedure is not found as the id has changed.